# JAVA: How to convert a string like this into a byte array

Tags: java

I received a string like this:
"1F8B0800000000000003E3E6CFDBA5C820CBC0C09122ECA1C8C0F281CDC54B2138D2CF99C9D0C87866B788E9FC37860700B43D2BB325000000"

and now I want convert this string to a byte array:
byte[] payload = new byte[] {0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xE3, 0xE6, 0xCF, 0xDB, 0xA5, 0xC8, 0x20, 0xCB, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x91, 0x22, 0xEC, 0xA1, 0xC8, 0xC0, 0xF2, 0x81, 0xCD, 0xC5,0x4B, 0x21, 0x38, 0xD2, 0xCF, 0x99, 0xC9, 0xD0, 0xC8, 0x78, 0x66, 0xB7, 0x88, 0xE9, 0xFC, 0x37, 0x86,0x07, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x3D, 0x2B, 0xB3, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

byte[] payload = new byte[] {0x1F, 0x8B, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xE3, 0xE6, 0xCF, 0xDB, 0xA5, 0xC8, 0x20, 0xCB, 0xC0, 0xC0, 0x91, 0x22, 0xEC, 0xA1, 0xC8, 0xC0, 0xF2, 0x81, 0xCD, 0xC5,0x4B, 0x21, 0x38, 0xD2, 0xCF, 0x99, 0xC9, 0xD0, 0xC8, 0x78, 0x66, 0xB7, 0x88, 0xE9, 0xFC, 0x37, 0x86,0x07, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x3D, 0x2B, 0xB3, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

Comment: Maybe you can use `new BigInteger(payloadString, 16).toByteArray();`.

Comment: but take care if the first byte is *negative*, that is, `> 0x7F` when using previous solution (could be a problem - byte `0x00` added in front to get a positive number)

Comment: `byte[] a = HexFormat.of().parseHex(s);`( >= Java 17)

Comment: See [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.

```
String hexString = "1F8B0800000000000003E3E6CFDBA5C820CBC0C09122ECA1C8C0F281C"
        + "DC54B2138D2CF99C9D0C87866B788E9FC37860700B43D2BB325000000";
```

Without a doubt, the simplest way is to use what [g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se) said in the comments above.

```
byte[] bytes = HexFormat.of(hexString).parseHex(s);
```

If you are running releases java 8 thru Java 16 the following will work.

- match two characters at a time and stream the results.
- convert the hex string in the capture group to a decimal byte
- then collect in an `Byte` array.

```
Byte[] bytes = Pattern.compile("(..)").matcher(hexString).results()
        .map(mr -> (byte)Integer.parseInt(mr.group(), 16))
        .toArray(Byte[]::new);
```